# Horizontal Ray Starting from Previous Day High Low to Current Bar

Tags: label, pine-script, line, indicator

I'm trying to plot previous day's high/low, here's the code:

```
//@version=5

indicator('PDHL', overlay=true)

show_pdhl = input(true, 'Show Previous Day High/Low')

[_from, p_high, p_low, p_mid, c_open] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [time, high[1], low[1], hl2[1], open], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)

if show_pdhl    
    p_high_line = line.new(_from, p_high, time, p_high, xloc.bar_time, color=color.red)
    line.delete(p_high_line[1])
    p_high_label = label.new(bar_index, p_high, style=label.style_label_left, size=size.small, color=#ffffff, text='PDH', textcolor=color.red)
    label.delete(p_high_label[1])

    p_low_line = line.new(_from, p_low, time, p_low, xloc.bar_time, color=color.green)
    line.delete(p_low_line[1])
    p_low_label = label.new(bar_index, p_low, style=label.style_label_left, size=size.small, color=#ffffff, text='PDL', textcolor=color.green)
    label.delete(p_low_label[1])
```

This plots the lines starting from the opening of the new day. What I'd like to be able to do is start the lines from the exact points where the high/low was created(for better reference) and extend till the current bar.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with the `security()` function. You need to keep track of the prices and their bar indices yourself.

Here is an example for the `high` price:

```
var prev_day_high = high
var prev_day_high_idx = bar_index
var prev_day_high_line = line.new(na, na, na, na)
var day_high = high
var day_high_idx = bar_index

is_new_day = ta.change(time("D"))

if (is_new_day)
    prev_day_high := day_high
    prev_day_high_idx := day_high_idx
    // Create your lines here

    day_high := high
    day_high_idx := bar_index
else
    // Update your lines' x2 here so they would extend to the current bar
    if (high > day_high)
        day_high := high
        day_high_idx := bar_index
```

Comment: Perfect! Created/updated the lines and labels and it's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so so much.