# Starting drawing line from previous candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm working on PDH/PDL indicator. Im newbie to the code and I try to learn.

For the moment all work fine but i want to add option to change the start line drawing.
-From new day
or
-From the orignal candle

For PDH new day drawing for example I have this :

```
dayh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

previousday_from = input.string(defval = "New day",title="Previous Day from",group = "Previous Level", options = ["New day","Origine"])

var line line_pdh = na

if ta.change(time("D"))
  if previousday_from == "New day"
    line_pdh := line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=dayh[1], x2=bar_index, y2=dayh[1], color=linecolordayh,   width=1) // Drawing from bar_index if new day
```

[Line from New day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTiYC.png)

So this code draw the line black on the screen, but i want if my option "from origine" is true, the line start at the high[1] 'D' candle and not the start day

[Line I want draw from orininal candle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIjnm.png)

For me to start the line from the original candle I try to do this

```
if ta.change(time("D"))
  if previousday_from == "New day" // x1= bar_index to put at actual value
    line_pdh := line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=dayh[1], x2=bar_index, y2=dayh[1], color=linecolordayh,   width=1) // Drawing from bar_index if new day
  else  // x1= dayh[1] to get the high[1] from previous day ?
     line_pdh := line.new(x1=dayh[1],, y1=dayh[1], x2=bar_index, y2=dayh[1], color=linecolordayh,   width=1) // Drawing from bar_index if new day
```

For me if I modify the x1 start with the dayh[1] i will put the high[1] "D" for me ? But not working

I hope you will help me, thanks you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Horizontal Ray Starting from Previous Day High Low to Current Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77161802/horizontal-ray-starting-from-previous-day-high-low-to-current-bar)

Comment: You cannot get the bar index of an event from the `security()` call. You need to keep track of that yourself. Look at the link I provided above.